# Please make [spark-cluster-framework] a synonym of [apache-spark]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [spark-cluster-framework](/questions/tagged/spark-cluster-framework) and [apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark) refer to the same thing.

[Spark's overview page](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) uses the following language

> Apache Spark is a fast and general-purpose cluster computing system.

which suggests that [spark-cluster-framework](/questions/tagged/spark-cluster-framework) should be a synonym of [apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do. Although the apache-spark can be seen as the succesor of spark questions could still address specific issues seen only by that specific implementation I guess. By synomizing this distinction is gone I believe....

Comment: @rene - I'm assuming that the only difference between the two is that before a certain version ([0.8.0](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-0-8-0-released.html)?) Spark was not an Apache project, and after that it was. As far as I know there is only one implementation of Spark, so it would be better to merge the tags and have people simply state their version of Spark when relevant.

Comment: I rather have one of the high-rep users in that tag chime in to verify that assumption

Comment: @rene: I agree that `spark-cluster-framework` should be a synonym of `apache-spark`.  Nick's assumption is right: Spark became an Apache project as of version 0.7.1+ and the development has moved from the UC Berkeley AMP Lab to Apache.  Aside from the name change, questions in both tags are talking about the same implementation and codebase.

Comment: OK, thanks for that clarification

Comment: Interesting side note, there also appears to be a [tag:spark], which is about something completely unrelated. Anyway, is there anything more we need to do to make this synonym happen?

Comment: Spark is a pretty popular project name.  In addition to Apache Spark, that tag has also been used for the [SPARK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARK_(programming_language)) programming language, the Spark Flex component, and the [Spark Java web framework](http://www.sparkjava.com/).